# i tried to display addition result to others activity but didn't appear

Tags: android

I am newbie at this javascript and android stuff.

I'm tried to add two number taken from "EditView" and display it in other activity.
But it's didn't show up anything.

here are the code.

public void lihathasil(View v) {

```
thn1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.datat1);
thn2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.datat2);
thn3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.datat3);
thn4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.datat4);
thn1cus = Integer.parseInt(thn1.getText().toString());
thn2cus = Integer.parseInt(thn2.getText().toString());
thn3cus = Integer.parseInt(thn3.getText().toString());
thn4cus = Integer.parseInt(thn4.getText().toString());
ab =  thn1cus + thn2cus + thn3cus + thn4cus;

Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GeneralReport.class);

i.putExtra("pertama",ab);
startActivity(i);

}
```

And here are the code in other activity to view the result

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_general_report);

tam1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tampilsatu);
val1=getIntent().getExtras().getString("pertama");
tam1.setText(val1);

}
```

when i run it's display nothing.

can anyone help to solved it.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

You pass the integer value in one activity and get the string value in other activity.

Other activty code :

```
val1=getIntent().getExtras().getIntExtra("pertama",0);
tam1.setText(String.valueof(val1));
```

Comment: then put val1=getIntent().getExtras().getIntExtra("pertama",0);

Comment: yes it is getInt() if use getExtras(). Because if you call getExtras() on getIntent() it returns Bundle containing all the extras added to the intent. but if you just need a single value then using getIntent().getIntExtra("key") is better.

Answer (score 0):

In your second Activity change this

> val1=getIntent().getExtras().getString("pertama");

to this

> val1=getIntent().getIntExtra("pertama", 0);

and change this

> tam1.setText(val1);

to this

> tam1.setText(String.valueOf(val1));

// Assuming val1 is defined as integer